# How to handle bodyParser errors in Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My limit is set to 5mb (see code below) and when I upload an image of greater size, I receive the payload error. How to handle payload errors in a better way like sending a JSON or HTML?

```sh
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
    at read (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
    at urlencodedParser (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:116:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (D:\Programming\Web Development\Projects\Imagify\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:119:7)
```

This is my Express code to set a limit to 5mb.

```js
app.use(express.json({ limit: '5mb' }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '5mb', extended: true }))
```

Comment: Create an [Express error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), check for that error and send a custom response.  In fact, you can send a custom response for any or all errors with the Express error handler.

Comment: I think handling `multipart/form-data` with a package like `multer` will be so great.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00! I created a middleware. But I am not able to understand how does it work. Since it's a middleware, won't it work before every route? How does it know when to fire?

Comment: @AnshAgarwal - I can't answer questions about code I can't see.  The error handling middleware is different (4 arguments instead of three) and nodejs knows the difference.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Check the answer I answered. But even with this, the AWS shows its own error page. Why? https://i.postimg.cc/kXcvw9ph/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a middleware just below the parsers. It worked.

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.type === 'entity.too.large')
        res.send(
            '<p align="center">Please upload an image below the defined limit of 5 MB. <br> Click <a href="/create">here</a> to visit the upload page again.</p>'
        )
    else res.redirect('/')
})
```